# how to load rdf file by virtuoso or other graph database?

Tags: tensorflow, graph, nlp, pytorch, virtuoso

I want to load freebase rdf file. but no documents. so I want to know how to load rdf file to virtuoso graph database, or other graph database.

Comment: Please go through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  You are required to show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: "no documents" for what? Virtuoso documentation is broad and deep at <http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/>. Bulk loading RDF files is covered [here](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtBulkRDFLoader). There's also [this third-party description of how they loaded Freebase into Virtuoso](https://github.com/sameersingh/nlp_serde/wiki/Virtuoso-Freebase-Setup).